# In elastic search, q=joh* is returning a correct set, but a JSON with match: joh* is not

Tags: elasticsearch

When I call this URL:

```
http://192.168.x.x:9200/identities/work/_search?q=joh*
```

ES is returning a limited (5) set of matches, starting with some indexes of people names John and Johnny etc. That seems to be the correct result.

But when I send this JSON to ES:

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "_all": "joh*"
    }
  }
}
```

I get results that I can't even logically explain. Seems rather random, and a lot of indexes too (hundreds, not a lot of johns and johnny's either ;))

Is this not the equivalent of the URL mentioned above? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call the following URL, what ES does implicitly is to create a `query_string` query not a `match` query

```
http://192.168.x.x:9200/identities/work/_search?q=joh*
```

So the equivalent JSON query would be:

```
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "joh*"
    }
  }
}
```

Moreover, `match` queries do not handle wildcards as in `joh*`, the `*` is considered and matched as a real character, not as a wildcard.